# How to get an only one connection for each client in java rmi?

Tags: java, rmi

I made a java RMI application. I need to get an only one connection for each client, to do the database operation. Is it possible?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Question is very vague here, you can't expect somebody will give you complete working code for your one liner thoughts. Also You should have prepared your question to show what you have tried to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Connections in RMI are well hidden from you. There is no way you can tell how many connections per client there are without 'netstat'. But if the client only ever calls from one thread at a time, there will never be more than one simultaneous connection from that client. You should also note that the TCP connection is dropped when there is no activity, at least in the Sun/Oracle implementation.

But I don't see what that has to do with databases. Possibly you are really trying to ask a different question entirely. I've answered the one you asked.